# Laravel relationship breaks after vue form submit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm currently learning Vue and using laravel as my back end. I have a relationship set for a forum where it'll fetch the author's username from the `User` model example below:

```
public function fetchAuthor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author', 'id');
    }
```

If I go from say the home page into the forum, this displays correctly with the username (rather than the stored user id of the topic) however,

Upon submitting a new topic it throws an error of:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'username' of undefined"

I have had a look around and cannot seem to find an answer of which works.. Here's my Vue script code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                topics: {
                    author: '',
                    topic: '',
                    content: '',
                },
                errors: [],
                forumTopics: [],
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
            this.fetchTopics();
        },
        ready() {
            this.updateContent()
        },
        methods: {
            updateContent: function (){
                this.$http.get('api/gameForum')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.forumTopics = response.data.forumTopics
                    });
                setTimeout(this.updateContent, 1000);
            },
            initAddTopic()
            {
                $("#add_topic_modal").modal("show");
            },
            createTopic()
            {
                axios.post('api/gameForum', {
                    topic: this.topics.topic,
                    content: this.topics.content,
                })
                    .then(response => {

                        this.reset();

                        $("#add_topic_modal").modal("hide");

                        this.forumTopics.push(response.data.topics);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.errors = [];
                        if (error.response.data.errors.topic) {
                            this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.topic[0]);
                        }

                        if (error.response.data.errors.content) {
                            this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.content[0]);
                        }
                    });
            },
            reset()
            {
                this.topics.topic = '';
                this.topics.content = ''
            },
            fetchTopics()
            {
                axios.get('api/gameForum')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.forumTopics = response.data.forumTopics;
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

and here is the controller (I'll be showing index function and the store function of which I am using:

```
public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->usergroup > 2)
        {
            $fetchTopics = ForumTopics::where('forum_type', 'game forum')
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->with('fetchAuthor')
                ->get();
        } else {
            $fetchTopics = ForumTopics::where('forum_type', 'game forum')
                ->where('deleted', 0)
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->with('fetchAuthor')
                ->get();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'forumTopics' => $fetchTopics
        ],200);
    }
```

here is the store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'topic' => 'required|max:40',
            'content' => 'required'
        ]);

        $forumTopics = ForumTopics::create([
            'author' => Auth::user()->id,
            'topic' => $request->get('topic'),
            'content' => $request->get('content'),
            'forum_type' => 'Game Forum'
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'topics' => $forumTopics,
            'message' => 'Success'
        ], 200);
    }
```

Here is the table view display where username is being called:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" style="margin-top:1%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="topic in forumTopics">
        <td>
            {{ topic.fetch_author.username }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ topic.topic }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE** - You can see I have tried running an updateContent() function, this was my last attempt before coming here.

Comment: Could you include the portion of your code where you reference username? I don't see username in any of the code snippets provided

Comment: @AlexHarris, sorry about that I have added it in now.

Comment: Apparently at least one member of `forumTopics` is being reset to a value that does not have a `fetch_author` member.

Comment: @RoyJ, any suggestions on what I can do? I have tried removing the reset() also but it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out using `this.forumTopics.push(response.data.topics);` was the wrong way to go within the create method. This would only pass back the userid rather than the username.

Within my fix (which I'm not sure is the correct route to go) I deleted:

`this.forumTopics.push(response.data.topics);`

and replaced it with: `this.fetchTopics();` so that it'd would then re fetch all of the topics which retain the `fetch_author` relationship.

It seems to work great but again, unsure if it's the best route..